# HTML/PHP Select refuses to store a value

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to make a dropdown list with values from a database, but when I try testing whether the value was taken in, I get nothing.

```
<select name = "student_id">
<option value="" >choose student</option>
<?php 
require_once('../mysqli_connect.php');
$getnames = @mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT student_id, first_name, last_name FROM students"); 

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($getnames))
{ 
?><option value = "<?php echo $row['student_id']; ?>">   
<?php echo $row['student_id'] . ' ' .$row['first_name'] . ' '. $row['last_name'];  
?></option>";   <?php
}
?>
</option> 
</select>
```

The list appears to be fine, showing the student id, first name and the last name of all entries in the database,  but when I test the value taken in with   this

```
$studentid = trim($_POST['student_id']); 

echo $studentid;

require_once ('../mysqli_connect.php');
?>
```

And it does not return anything. Everything seems to work with other lists where I did not use any loops and just typed out each option, but I can't find issues In the loop.

Sorry for the terrible question.

Comment: `<option value = "<?php $row['student_id']; ?>">`  you forgot to echo it. So what you're actually getting is `<option value = "">` everywhere.

Comment: Did you try taking out your if (isset($_POST['submit'])) conditional? From the code you show, I don't see that there would be a submit parameter sent.

Comment: @Qirel I have tried that, the echo did not change anything

Comment: @Ahop Yes, I've tried it, still nothing. I should probably remove it from the post for clarity.

Comment: Try to avoid using the error-suppressing `@` operator, *especially* when making database calls where errors are very important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
?><option value = "<?php $row['student_id']; ?>">   
                         ^---missing echo
```

If you'd done any basic debugging, like a `view source` of your generated html, you'd have seen that all of your option values are empty...

So,  not, it's not the option refusing to store a value. it's doing EXACTLY what YOU told it to: send an empty/blank value to the server.

Comment: You could add  that he could use short echo tags `<?= $var ?>`

Comment: If OP can't figure out "missing echo", then OP should probably reconsider their career choice...

Comment: I have tried adding echo, but it returns empty values either way

Comment: so do `var_dump($row)` and see what you are getting from the fetch call...

Comment: Also remove the error surpression (`@`) from your mysqli_query.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes that... actually fixed it.